# Pivot column to populate with values from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a SQL Server database table in which I need to convert (pivot?) the values of the `Vaccination Name` column, each into their own columns.  Then I need to populate those columns with values from `Vaccination Date`.  I'm not much of a programmer, and my research hasn't found something to fit my needs.

Table example

[image]

Comment: You have multiple dates for each Vaccination, which do you want to display?

Comment: @ollie.  I should have provided more detail.  The reason that I need to get the vaccination names in separate columns is that each pet in the table needs to  only have one row.  They currently have multiple.  An example screenshot is here - http://imgur.com/a/eaEq5.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the max date for each pet/vaccine combination then? If a pet has multiple entries for a Rabies vaccine, which one do you want?

Comment: @ollie - The most recent date, if there's more than one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to get the max date for each vaccination for each pet. The simplest is probably to use some sort of conditional logic with an aggregate function:

```
select 
  Pet_Name,
  Bordetella = max(case when Vaccination_Name = 'Bordetella' then Vaccination_Date end),
  CanineDistemper = max(case when Vaccination_Name = 'Canine Distemper' then Vaccination_Date end),
  Rabies = max(case when Vaccination_Name = 'Rabies' then Vaccination_Date end)
from <table>
group by Pet_Name;
```

Or since you're using SQL Server you can use the PIVOT function:

```
select Pet_name,
  Bordetella, [Canine Distemper], Rabies
from 
(
  select 
    Pet_Name, 
    Vaccination_Name,
    Vaccination_Date
  from <table>
) d
pivot
(
  max(Vaccination_Date)
  for Vaccination_Name in (Bordetella, [Canine Distemper], Rabies)
) piv;
```

Both will return the same result for you. I even created a [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/667162) for you to play with.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!